# All of my debug configurations were erased after updating Android Studio, how do I fix this?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging

I am writing a Flutter app in Android Studio. I had no problem debugging, I just clicked on "debug" and it worked. After updating, it does not see my phone - VS Code has no problem - and does not have any run configurations. Clicking the debug button opens the Edit Configuration dialogue but it tells me that lib/main.dart isn't in my project which it clearly is. It's completely useless now.

error message: `Entrypoint file not found at lib/main.dart`

I've tried setting the location of main.dart manually, it still says it doesn't exist or it's not in my project.

Comment: make sure to open the root of your project